# Using batch echo to write a vbe file (characters are not escaped)

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, escaping, encode

So I'm currently writing a tutorial about security and for that reason I have to write a vbe file (encoded script written in VBScript) using a batch file.

So, I just have to write this to a file:

```
#@~^mgAAAA==6   P3MDKDP"+k;:PH+XY~@#@&fks~D;EdO{6k^+SPhnk/Co8WX~~AMkYnm6ks+B~T+O|wmYtBPDn:a{2lDtS~6kxms{alY4~@#@&s+k/Con8K6~',h/T4GavJKndDJ~~8BPEwlDlV,2M.WMJbP@#@&2zEAAA==^#~@
```

(Note: There are some characters that cannot be printed above).

But the problem is that I never managed to write it successfully, I tried escaping all the characters using instructions from http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php and it didn't work.

I tried using `DelayedExpansion` like this:

```
SET "foo=#@~^mgAAAA==6  P3MDKDP"+k;:PH+XY~@#@^&fks~D;EdO{6k^+SPhnk/Co8WX~~AMkYnm6ks+B~T+O|wmYtBPDn:a{2lDtS~6kxms{alY4~@#@&s+k/Con8K6~',h/T4GavJKndDJ~~8BPEwlDlV,2M.WMJbP@#@^&2zEAAA==^#~@ "
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(
 echo !foo!
) > test.vbe
```

And it did not work either, I have problems with characters that are not escaped.

Any ideas?? Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is obvious, that is a quotation mark after [*...P3MDKDP*]. Since you assign the variable "foo" to jumble characters with a open and a close quotation mark, like so `SET "foo=..."`, batch think you stop assigning "foo" after [*...P3MDKDP*]. This leaves [*+k;:PH+XY~.....*] alone, without assigning to a variable or working with commands. Batch can't recognize it, and so the command prompt quit automatically.
What you can do is, assign the part after the quotation mark to another variable, I named it "foo2" in the following example:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

SET "foo=#@~^mgAAAA==6  P3MDKDP""
SET "foo2=+k;:PH+XY~@#@^&fks~D;EdO{6k^+SPhnk/Co8WX~~AMkYnm6ks+B~T+O|wmYtBPDn:a{2lDtS~6kxms{alY4~@#@&s+k/Con8K6~',h/T4GavJKndDJ~~8BPEwlDlV,2M.WMJbP@#@^&2zEAAA==^#~@ "

echo !foo!!foo2!>test.vbe

pause >nul
```

And also, if you add another quotation mark before / after the quotation mark, like so [*P3MDKDP* **""**], even though you did not assign the second part to a new variable, it still work, but it output an extra quotation mark in the string.

Comment: Indeed, that was the problem, it works now, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

maybe this little trick helps you:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=[]" %%n in ('find /n "REM DATA:" "%~dpnx0"') do set /a n=%%n
more +%n%  "%~dpnx0">test.vbe
REM rest or your batchfile
goto :eof
REM DATA:
#@~^mgAAAA==6  P3MDKDP"+k;:PH+XY~@#@^&fks~D;EdO{6k^+SPhnk/Co8WX~~AMkYnm6ks+B~T+O|wmYtBPDn:a{2lDtS~6kxms{alY4~@#@&s+k/Con8K6~',h/T4GavJKndDJ~~8BPEwlDlV,2M.WMJbP@#@^&2zEAAA==^#~@
```

(this trick avoids any character escaping or splitting the string. Can also be used to write a multiline text)

Comment: Nice trick but there is a problem, it does not write correctly the TAB characters in the file test.vbe

Comment: that's right. `more` converts a TAB to spaces. (I didn't notice, there is a TAB in the string - it's also converted to spaces here on SO)